# Angular 8 binding by value or reference?

Tags: typescript, angular8

A warning: I am currently working through an online course to learn Angular.

Currently, I am working on services. The course requested an exercise that is about injecting a service into another service.

So, I have the first Service `user-switched-counter.service.ts` which looks like this:

```
export class UserSwitchedCounterService {
    switchCount : number = 0;
}
```

And then I got the second service `user.service.ts` which looks like this:

```
import { UserSwitchedCounterService } from "./user-switched-counter.service";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    activeUsers = ['Max', 'Anna'];
    inactiveUsers = ['Chris', 'Manu'];

    constructor(private userSwitchedCounterService : UserSwitchedCounterService ) {}

    switchToActiveUsers(idx : number) {
        this.activeUsers.push(this.inactiveUsers[idx]);
        this.inactiveUsers.splice(idx, 1);    
        this.userSwitchedCounterService.switchCount += 1;
    }   

    switchToInactiveUsers(idx : number) {
        this.inactiveUsers.push(this.activeUsers[idx]);
        this.activeUsers.splice(idx, 1);    
        this.userSwitchedCounterService.switchCount += 1;
    }

}
```

As you can see the second service counts the user switch. This exercise does not have any particular meaning - it is just an example to learn about services.

Now, I created a component to display this count on the website.

The typescript file of the component `user-switched-count.component.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserSwitchedCounterService } from '../user-switched-counter.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-switched-count',
  templateUrl: './user-switched-count.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-switched-count.component.css']
})
export class UserSwitchedCountComponent implements OnInit {

  userSwitched = 0;

  constructor(private userSwitchedCountService : UserSwitchedCounterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userSwitched = this.userSwitchedCountService.switchCount;
  }

}
```

And the output of this component is `user-switched-count.component.html` which looks like this:

```
<p>User Switch Count: {{userSwitched}}</p>
```

Now, in that case the count value does not get reflected in the output. What I mean by that: No matter how many times I switch a user from active to inactive and the other way around - the counter remains 0.

HOWEVER, if I change `user-switched-count.component.ts` to this here:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserSwitchedCounterService } from '../user-switched-counter.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-switched-count',
  templateUrl: './user-switched-count.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-switched-count.component.css']
})
export class UserSwitchedCountComponent implements OnInit {

  userSwitchedCountServiceAccessor;

  constructor(private userSwitchedCountService : UserSwitchedCounterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userSwitchedCountServiceAccessor = this.userSwitchedCountService;
  }

}
```

And then the `user-switched-count.component.html` output to this here:

```
<p>User Switch Count: {{userSwitchedCountServiceAccessor.switchCount}}</p>
```

Then everything works alright and the counter correctly gets counted up.

Now, the difference here is that in the first (not working) case, I assigned `this.userSwitched = this.userSwitchedCountService.switchCount;` to a local property.

While in the second case I copy the whole service object.

Now, my question: Is the first case a copy by value and the second case a copy by reference?

Why does case 2 work and case 1 does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First case is copy by value. 
Second case is read value directly from service.
PS: Hook 'ngOnInit' will be executed only once (you need real time value)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Doesn't that contradict the principle of binding variables in Angular?